# Регулярное выражение, выделяющее слово с символами вокруг

Tags: регулярные-выражения

```
stopWordsContents.forEach(word => {
 const pattern = '(\\s|\^)(' + word + ')(\\s|\$)';
 const re = new RegExp(pattern, 'gi');
 content = content.replace(re, '<span class="stop-word">$2</span>');
});
```

подскажите как сделать так чтобы эта функция оборачивала в спан не только слова разделенные с двух сторон пробелами, но и если по краям какие то символы. Например: "%::,,%№слово" нужно обернуть

Comment: `const pattern = '\\b' + word.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + '\\b'`, а потом `.replace(re, '<span class="stop-word">$&</span>')`? Какие у вас "слова"? Только из букв ASCII или русские?

Comment: ваш шаблон не работает, кириллица только будет в стоп словах

Comment: Тогда удалите `\b` или используйте свой шаблон для границы слова. Что имеется в виду под "словом"? Русские и не только слова из букв?

Comment: Спасибо, огоромное, Виктор! Единственное почему то в центр слова вставляется пробел  когда такой паттерн сделал "word.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');"

Comment: это не пробел оказывается. Проблема в том, что если например word дурак и рак, то рак будет выделяться внутри выделенного дурак. Нужно этого избежать как то

Comment: Разобрался. Спасибо еще раз. Виктор!

Comment: Я добавил ответ, надеюсь, то что нужно. Если ответ ниже помог решить проблему, пожалуйста, отметьте его как решение, поставив галочку напротив и проголосуйте за решение. См. [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете так называемые "пробельные" границы слова, `(\s|^)` и `(\s|$)` (нельзя экранировать знаки `^` и `$`, иначе они лишатся своих особенных значений начала и конца слов). Сразу замечу, что вместо обычной подмаски `(\s|$)` вам следует использовать блок предварительного просмотра `(?=\s|$)` или (лучше) `(?!\S)`, чтобы находились последовательные слова (например `слово слово`).

Так как вы "оборачиваете" "слова", которые могут содержать специальные метасимволы, `word` необходимо экранировать.

Так, регулярка будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
let pattern = '(\\s|^)(' + word.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + ')(?!\\S)'
```

В шаблоне имеются две захватываемые подмаски, `(\\s|^)` и `(слово)`. Первая нужна для того, чтобы восстановить пробел, если он будет найден. Вторая — чтобы подставить слово внутрь тега. То есть в шаблоне замены нужно указать две обратные ссылки.

Целый код на JavaScript:

```js
let content = 'Слово слово словоохотлиый',
    word = 'слово';
let pattern = '(\\s|^)(' + word.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + ')(?!\\S)';
const re = new RegExp(pattern, 'gi');
content = content.replace(re, '$1<span class="stop-word">$2</span>');
console.log(content);
```

Comment: Виктор, нужно еще чтобы <h1>Слово</h1> или какие-нибудь ^&%&^%Слово тоже выделялись

Comment: @БулатНасибуллин Т.е. границу слова всё-таки надо изменить? Ну так определитесь с ней. Если граница слова - это любой символ отличный от английских и русских букв (+ цифр), можно использовать ``'([^a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ0-9]|^)(' + word.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + ')(?![a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ0-9])'``

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо!